# I need to get a count of values (grouped) in a csv column

Tags: php, arrays, csv, count, grouping

I need to get a count of the first column's values. These ID's might or might not exist in any given .csv file I receive. So I need to loop through the .csv file looking at the first column and either adding it to a holding array ($PWSs) if it doesn't exist or incrementing the count in this holding array if I've already added it.

I have the first loop using fgetcsv()..this works for cracking into the file:

```
$PWSs = array();

$handle2 = fopen ($uploadfileandpath,"r");
while ($field2array = fgetcsv ($handle2, 130000, ",")) 
{
    // Here is where I would add value or increment $PWSs array
    while (?)
    {
        if ($field2array[0] != ?)
        {
            // Add or increment
        }
    }
}
```

Here is actual data. The first column has IDs for Public Water Systems. I need to count them.

```
"00513","08/13/2009","090834311A","R","4","OR1000x6","N","N","E",,1,".73","COLILERT"
"00513","08/13/2009","090834312A","R","39","OR1000x6","N","N","E",,1,".35","COLILERT"
"00154","08/13/2009","090835401A","R","300 Falls Road","OR100016","N","N","E",,1,".10","COLILERT"
"95343","08/13/2009","090835601A","R","Room 1 Sink","OR1000x6","N","N","E",,1,,"COLILERT"
"94585","08/14/2009","090837701A","R","Kitchen","OR1000x6","N","N","E",,1,,"COLILERT"
"94704","08/14/2009","090837801A","R","Outside Tap","OR1000x6","N","N","E",,1,,"COLILERT"
"01430","08/14/2009","090838201A","R","100 Deer Park Ln OT","OR1000x6","N","N","E",,1,,"COLILERT"
"00625","08/14/2009","090839001A","R","Dano and N Rose","OR100016","N","N","E",,1,".35","COLILERT"
"00405","08/17/2009","090840301A","R","Westmont Drive","OR100016","N","N","E",,1,".28","COLILERT"
"01031","08/17/2009","090840401A","R","Unit 2 Faucet","OR100016","N","N","E",,1,,"COLILERT"
"00625","08/17/2009","090840601A","R","Luman Road","OR1000x6","N","N","E",,1,".35","COLILERT"
"00513","08/17/2009","090841001A","R","40","OR1000x6","N","N","E",,1,".18","COLILERT"
"00513","08/17/2009","090841002A","R","10","OR1000x6","N","N","E",,1,".16","COLILERT"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fh = fopen('file.csv', 'rb');

$PWS = array();
while($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    $PWS[$row[0]]++;
}
```

Basically it'll populate the PWS using the first column values as keys, and increment them as they come along. Afterwards, given your sample csv above, you'd end up with

```
$PWS = array(
    '00513' => 4
    '00154' => 1
    '95343' => 1
    '94585' => 1
etc...
);
```

Comment: Thanks Marc B. This code thanks to you works, but I also get an Undefined index:
$fh = fopen ($uploadfileandpath,"r");
$PWSs = array();

while($row = fgetcsv($fh,130000,",")) {
    $PWSs[$row[0]]++;  //THIS LINE RETURNS AN UNDEFINED INDEX FOR EVERY NEW VALUE (IT STILL ADDS THEM UP)
}

foreach($PWSs as $key => $value) {
   print "$key: $value<br>";
}

fclose($fh);

Comment: My comment above isn't too readable. Here is the one line that gets an "Undefined Index" error. (I can't change error reporting level): $PWSs[$row[0]]++;

Comment: Ok, I gave up trying to be clever and I was clever. I put this in at the top of the page to avoid the UNDEFINED INDEX NOTICE: error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

Comment: You can do an if (!isset($PWSs[$key[0]]) { $PWSs[$key[0]] = 0} before the increment

Comment: @Marc please edit your answer, so researchers don't need to read the comments for best practice.

Comment: @Marc I find myself wanting to use this page again as a duplicate, but your answer is not good enough.  Please improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_pws()
{
    $PWSs = array();

    $handle2 = fopen ($uploadfileandpath,"r");
    while ($field2array = fgetcsv ($handle2, 130000, ",")) 
    {
        if(!in_array($field2array[0], $PWSs))
        {
            array_push($PWSs, array('key'=>$field2array[0], 'count'=>1));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($PWSs as &$PWS)
            {
                if($PWS['key'] == $field2array[0])
                {
                    ++$PWS['count'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $PWSs;
}
```

I haven't actually run and tested this script, so hopefully it works and it's what you're looking for ;)

Edit: Thanks for pointing that out dq. Again, I haven't tested it (not on a machine with PHP installed atm), so hopefully it still works (if it worked in the first place) :P

Comment: to clarify, this counts how many different unique IDs there are, not simply how many rows contain IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one **while** loop. Your outer while loop will stop when it hits the eof, because fgetcsv() will return FALSE.

Then just test for the column to be NULL or "" an empty string. If the column did not exist in the given array, you should use **isset()** to make sure it exists first in your conditional.