# Group by a column from csv and sum the values from another (PHP)

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv like this:

```
25/07/2016 3
25/07/2016 4
26/07/2016 4
26/07/2016 1
```

And the output that i expect, it have to be like this

```
25/07/2016 7
26/07/2016 5
```

I want to do this only using PHP.
I have to mention that i am not using mysql and i don't want to. 
Is there a solution to do that?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: You want to read from a file csv and create the output file csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"25/07/2016","3"
"25/07/2016","4"
"26/07/2016","4"
"26/07/2016","1"
```

For e.g. Let's say you have CSV file that contains data as above.

```
$arr = array();
$handle = fopen("example.csv", "r");
while(!feof($handle))
{
    $arrOfCSVLine = fgetcsv($handle);
    $date = $arrOfCSVLine[0];
    $no = $arrOfCSVLine[1];

   if(!array_key_exists($data,$arr))
   {
       $arr[$date] = $no;
   }
   else
   {
       $arr[$date] += $no;
   }

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

check this code..

Comment: This is what i need! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this. This is just an edited version from [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610959/i-need-to-get-a-count-of-values-grouped-in-a-csv-column).

```
$my_file = fopen('file.csv', 'rb');

$my_array = array();
while($row = fgetcsv($my_file)) {
    $my_array[$row[0]] += $row[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$finalOutput = array();
$file = fopen('myCSVFile.csv', 'r'); 
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  if(isset($finalOutput[$line[0]])){
     $finalOutput[$line[0]] = $line[1] + $finalOutput[$line[0]];
   } else {
     $finalOutput[$line[0]] = $line[1];
   }
}
print_r($finalOutput);
```