# PHP - Count Distinct Value in a CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file with a very large number of item (5000 lines) in this format

```
storeId,bookId,nb
124,48361,0
124,48363,6
125,48362,8
125,48363,2
126,28933,4
142,55433,6
142,55434,10
171,55871,7
171,55872,6
```

I need to count the number of stores in the file, so for exemple with the line above the result should be `5`. But I need to doo it with 5000 lines so I can't just loop.

How can I achieve that?

I also need too  return the max quantity, so `10`

I began by converting the file into an array:

```php
if (file_exists($file)) {
            $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));

            #Stores
            $storeIds = array_column($csv, 0);
            $eachStoreNb = array_count_values($storeIds);
            $storeCount = count($eachStoreNb);

        }

        print_r($storeCount);
```

Is there a better way to do it? Faster ? Maybe without using the array

Comment: Faster maybe needing less passes but that would hardly make a significant difference.

Comment: In AWK this is trivial, and can be done with few lines of code. Just add +1 to the key of store. Like:  stores[123] +=1 .   I am not sure if PHP has similar on-demand keylists, but it could be in that direction you need to look. If PHP is not a demand from you, I would be happy to post an AWK solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610959/i-need-to-get-a-count-of-values-grouped-in-a-csv-column

Comment: Why do you need this to be faster? How many seconds does it take now? and how many seconds should it take ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faster here would come in the context of micro-optimization, however you can see an improvement in memory usage.

- You could just read the file line by line instead of collecting all store IDs in an array and then doing an array_count_values() saving you an extra loop and unnecessary linear storage of all duplicate values.
- Store IDs would just be made as a key for an associative array.
- For max NB, you can just keep a `max` variable keeping the track of max value using `max()` function. Rest is self-explanatory.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$file = 'test.csv';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $fp = fopen($file ,'r');
    $max_nb = 0;
    $store_set = [];
    fgetcsv($fp); // ignoring headers
    while(!feof($fp)){
        $row = fgetcsv($fp);
        $store_set[$row[0]] = true;
        $max_nb = max($max_nb,end($row));
    }

    fclose($fp);

    echo "Num Stores : ",count($store_set),"<br/>";
    echo "Max NB : ",$max_nb;

}else{
    echo "No such CSV file found.";
}
```

**Note:** For profiling, I suggest you to try both scripts using [`xdebug`](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

Answer (score 0):

What if you looped through the file line by line?
I mean ...

```
$datas = [];
$handle = fopen("filename.csv", "r");

$flagFirstLine = true;
while(!feof($handle)){
    //dont read first line
    if($flagFirstLine) continue;
    $flagFirstLine = false;

    $csvLine = fgetcsv($handle);
    $storeID = $csvLine[0];

    $datas[] = $storeID;
}

echo "all row: " . count($datas);
echo "\nnum store: " . count(array_unique($datas));
```

Comment: Is this faster? Or just a different way to do it? Have you tested both to see if this really makes a difference?

Comment: @nice_dev yeah, i see. I just changed my code. How do you feel?

Answer (score 0):

Solution in AWK, to compare the difference.  This includes the count of each store as well. AWK should be able to process millions in less than 1 second. I use the same to filter duplicates from a file.

```
BEGIN{   # Set some variables initially
  FS=","   # field separator for INPUT
  mymax=0  # init variable mymax
}
NR>1 {            # skip the header line, this matches line 2 onwards
  mycount[$1]++   # increase associative array at that position
  if ($3>mymax){  # compare with max
  mymax=$3
  }

}
END{              # finally print results
  for (i in mycount){
    if (length(i)>0){
       print "value " i  " has " mycount[i]
    }
   }
  print "Maximum value is "  mymax
}
```

Comment: I am getting `Maximum value is nb`   because `nb` is the max value for this third column. 

Comment: Ahh, yes sorry! My test file had the header left out. just change line 5 to read  "NR>1 {"  to skip the header line. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

An answer with `awk` would be:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {getline}
         { a[$1]++; m=$3>m?$3:m }
         END{ for (i in a){ print i, a[i] };
              print "Number of stores",length(a), "max:",m}' testfile
```

1. `getline` to skip the first line
2. increment the element with the value of the first column `$1` in array `a` with one, and keep the max value in `m`
3. loop over the array a and print all counts  (optional)
4. print the total 'Number of stores', and the max value.

output:

```
124 52
125 52
126 26
142 52
171 52
Number of stores 5 max: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

What 'nice_dev' says, but a little more compact.

```
$fp = fopen('<your_file>', 'r');

fseek($fp, strpos($content, "\n") + 1); // skip first line
$stores = [];
while($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    $stores[$row[0]] = max([($stores[$row[0]] ?? 0), $row[2]]);
}
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/HNQfV).